# Find total number of APIs used in an android application source code?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, api

i want to find out total number of android APIs (Classes and Methods) used in my android application source code. but i want to do it programmatically. can any one suggest me how can i do so??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't think that there is a *straight* forward way to do so. However  you may try to convert .apk to .jar and .class to .java (decompile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [Reflections API](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/).

You can get the list of classes using the following code :

```
Reflections ref = new Reflections("package_name");
Set<Class<?>> classes = ref.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
```

Then by using the [Class.getDeclaredMethods()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods%28%29) or [Class.getMethods()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29) you can get the list of methods.

Answer (score 1):

The eclipse metrics plugin looks promising. It is not specially designed for android but there's a chance that it will provide you with (most of) the informations you need.

**Reference**

- [project on sourceforge](http://metrics2.sourceforge.net/)